# Add 30 minutes to the current time in java

Tags: java, android

I want to get `current time` in my application.

Then i want to add `30 minutes` to the current time.

What is the best practice to achieve this?

I am able to get start and stop time from my web service.
eg: ((start time)11:00 am to (stop time) 11:00 pm) 
now, i would like to add `30 minutes` to the current time till the stop time is reached.

Comment: Use `Calender` for refrences http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: thanks samir.
i am getting start time and stop time from web service.
EX:((start time)11:00 am to 11:00 pm(stop time)) after getting this time i want to get current time in my application and divide the time in to 30 minutes time slot till the stop time??

Comment: Or `System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000*60*30;` if time in milliseconds is required.

Comment: ok samir let me try this

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
```

And to output the time you could use

```
// 24 hours format
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
// AM/PM format
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");

System.out.println(df.format(now.getTime()));
```

Comment: Just use SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");

Answer (score 14):

Use the following:

```
//get current Time
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//now add half an hour, 1 800 000 miliseconds = 30 minutes
long halfAnHourLater = currentTime + 1800000;
```

Answer (score 11):

```
System.currentTimeMillis()+(30*60*1000);
```